# Mark Down Specific Dates On WPF Calendar

Tags: c#, wpf

I am trying to markdown specific date from database source on WPF Calendar Control.

Here's the code snippet.

XAML

```
<Style x:Key="calendarDayButtonStyle" TargetType="CalendarDayButton">
<Calendar Name="CalendarSelectDate" />
```

.cs Code.

```
var dateList = GetDatesFromDB();
Style dayButtonStyle = (Style)this.Resources["calendarDayButtonStyle"];
foreach (DateObject date in dateList)
{
  var DataTrigger dataTrigger = new DataTrigger() { Binding = new Binding("Date"), Value = new DateTime(date.Year, date.Month, date.Day) }; // 
  dataTrigger.Setters.Add(new Setter(FontWeightProperty, FontWeights.Bold));
  dayButtonStyle.Triggers.Add(dataTrigger);  // This will throw TriggerCollection -exception.
}
calendarDayButtonStyle.CalendarDayButtonStyle = dayButtonStyle;  // this will sealed TriggerCollection.
```

This code works on initial run-time.

But, if run it again on run-time events, say if i added new dates into the database then run the code again, it will throw `After a 'TriggerCollection' is in use (sealed), it cannot be modified.` error.

What i understand, after the style is assigned to the calendar, the `TriggerCollection` is sealed.

Is there better way to dynamically mark down dates on WPF Calendar ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a new `Style` each time. You may base it on the the one that you have defined in the XAML using the `BasedOn` property:

```
var dateList = GetDatesFromDB();
Style dayButtonStyle = new Style() { BasedOn = (Style)this.Resources["calendarDayButtonStyle"] };
foreach (DateObject date in dateList)
{
    var dataTrigger = new DataTrigger() { Binding = new Binding("Date"), Value = new DateTime(date.Year, date.Month, date.Day) };
    dataTrigger.Setters.Add(new Setter(FontWeightProperty, FontWeights.Bold));
    dayButtonStyle.Triggers.Add(dataTrigger);
}
dayButtonStyle.Seal();
calendarDayButtonStyle.CalendarDayButtonStyle = dayButtonStyle;
```

Comment: Thank you. But unfortunately, it produces this error `'Can only base on a Style with target type that is base type 'IFrameworkInputElement'`. But, your answer give me idea. I just code the style on .cs. Now the the trigger to mark down specific dates, works dynamically. :)

Comment: The calendarDayButtonStyle must have the same `TargetType` as the dayButtonStyle.